# How to get a value from one pyspark dataframe using where clause

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am very new to Pyspark. So I have one requirement in which I have to get one column say 'id'  from one MYSQL table and for each id, I need to get 'HOST' value which is column in another MYSQL table. So 1st part I have completed and I am getting id by using below piece of code.

```
criteria_df = read_data_from_table(criteria_tbl)
```

```
datasource_df = read_data_from_table(data_source_tbl)
```

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

for row in criteria_df.collect(): 
  account_id = row["account_id"]
  criteria_name = row["criteria"]
  datasource_df = datasource_df.select(F.col('host')).where(F.col('id') == account_id)
  datasource_df.show()
```

But when I am trying to get host value for each id, I am not getting any value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put the `where` clause before the `select` clause, otherwise it always return nothing because the column in the `where` clause does not exist.

```
datasource_df = datasource_df.where(F.col('id') == account_id).select(F.col('host'))
```

Also for this type of query, it's better to do a `join`, instead of collecting dataframes and comparing them row by row.

Comment: Okay! So after join, I can easily iterate the dataframe that is resulted.

Comment: @VishnuChaturvedi iteration of dataframes are generally slow. It's better to use spark sql functions to operate on dataframes in parallel, which gives much better performance

Answer (score 2):

You can use the semi-join:

```
datasource_df.join(criteria_df, on=datasource_df['id'] == criteria_df['account_id'], how='left_semi')\
.select(F.col('host'))
```